# How to send message to multiple number in WhatsApp in one time?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to send a message to multiple phone numbers via WhatsApp using Flutter:

```
sendMessage() async {
  var number = ["201020402642", "201030666895"];
  var baseUrl = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send/";

  var urlIos = "";

  number.forEach((element) async {
    var url = baseUrl +"?phone=${element} &text=msg";
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      print("not installed");
    }
  });
}
```

It only sends a message to the last number.

Is there a way to send a message to a group of numbers?

Comment: What you got in the console for first number? "not installed" or nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way to send a message for more than 1 number at the same time using deep links. The only way you can do something like this is by using the WhatsApp business API through REST requests. There are some third-party software with this feature like https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp

Here is the WhatsApp API doc

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/#sending-messages