# Create broadcast on whatsapp by List of number

Tags: flutter, dart

if I have List of number in My app , how can create broadcast groub on whatsapp by flutter

```
List<String> recipients = ['0185889898', '0125555555','012552335555'];
    String massage = 'Hello this is a broadcast message';
```

```
i need a method to open broadcast on whatsapp by my List
```

Comment: [See this answer ,it may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972975/11217742)